# asp.net: Update page contents without refresh (Partial Page Update)

Tags: c#, asp.net, partial-page-refresh

Actually i am trying to update a page without refresh of whole page i.e. Partial Page Update. Web page structure is

```
<%@ Page Title="Test Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="dropDownName" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>                
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                     Last update:  <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i can see that when ever my event fires, it does every thing right like reading the contents, updating the controls on page with right updated information and adding the contents webControls to place holder like this

```
void Contnt_Update(object sender)
{
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newLabel);   
}
```

but it just simply not updating the 'Views' (mean i don't see the updated info on the web page) nor it updates the Time of 'Last Update'. 
Any idea what i am doing wrong? Any help will be really appreciated because i have spent quite good time on it and not getting any where ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to force the update with: `UpdatePanel.Update();`, and follow the other recommendations given here: [ASP.NET refresh Update Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260699/asp-net-refresh-update-panel)

**Update**:
Another technique to force the refresh of the UpdatePanel, without any action from the user, is to include a Timer in the panel, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369459/how-can-i-refresh-a-asp-page-from-code-behind-c-sharp).

Comment: i tried it but no luck : ( .. any other idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I have also seen this kind of code in similar situations, in addition to adding to the placeholder (but I guess you also saw it): UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(newLabel);

Comment: By the way, does it work well with a full postback, if you don't use the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Yeah it works with full post back.. additionally it also work if i add a Button in update panel and <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers> and then i click the button it works. But if i call the button click without clicking it , it doesn't work..

Comment: How do you call the button click without clicking it? It should be called like this  __doPostBack(‘btnID’,”)

Comment: i am calling it like this UpdateButtonCall(this, new EventArgs());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104743/discussion-between-banker-box-and-connorsfan).